# Determining the time complexity of my program?

Tags: java, algorithm

My program gets the symmetric difference between two lists.
Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.*;

    /**
     * A class to find the symmetric difference between two lists.
     */

    public class SymDifference
    {
    /**
     * Finds the symmetric difference between two sorted lists.
     *
     * @param L1     first list
     * @param L2     second list
     * @param Result list with the symmetric difference
     */
    static <AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>> void symDifference(List<AnyType> L1, List<AnyType> L2,
                                                                            List<AnyType> Result)
    {
        //create two iterators to go through the list
        ListIterator<AnyType> iterL1 = L1.listIterator();
        ListIterator<AnyType> iterL2 = L2.listIterator();

        //create two anytype objs
        AnyType itemL1 = null;
        AnyType itemL2 = null;

        //gets the first two items of the lists
        if (iterL1.hasNext() && iterL2.hasNext())
        {
            itemL1 = iterL1.next();
            itemL2 = iterL2.next();
        }

        //use a while loop to compare elements of lists
        while (itemL1 != null && itemL2 != null)
        {
            int compareResult = itemL1.compareTo(itemL2);

            //elements are the same so go on to the next items
            if (compareResult == 0)
            {
                //get next item for list L1
                if (iterL1.hasNext())
                {
                    itemL1 = iterL1.next();
                }
                else
                {
                    itemL1 = null;
                }
                //get next item for list L2
                if (iterL2.hasNext())
                {
                    itemL2 = iterL2.next();
                }
                else
                {
                    itemL2 = null;
                }
            }
            // the item of L1 comes after the item of L2, add item from L2 to results
            else if (compareResult < 0)
            {
                Result.add(itemL1);

                //get next item for list L1
                if (iterL1.hasNext())
                {
                    itemL1 = iterL1.next();
                }
                //get next item for list L2
                else
                {
                    itemL1 = null;
                }
            }
            // the item of L1 comes before the item of L2, add item from L1 to results
            else
            {
                Result.add(itemL2);

                //get next item for list L1
                if (iterL2.hasNext())
                {
                    itemL2 = iterL2.next();
                }
                //get next item for list L2
                else
                {
                    itemL2 = null;

                }
            }

        }

        //add remaining items from list L1
        while (itemL1 != null)
        {

            Result.add(itemL1);
            if (iterL1.hasNext())
            {
                itemL1 = iterL1.next();
            }
            else
            {
                itemL1 = null;
            }

        }

        //add remaining items from list L2
        while (itemL2 != null)
        {

            Result.add(itemL2);
            if (iterL2.hasNext())
            {
                itemL2 = iterL1.next();
            }
            else
            {
                itemL2 = null;
            }

        }
    }

    //tester class
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add(1);
        a.add(3);
        a.add(5);
        a.add(7);
        a.add(9);
        a.add(12);

        ArrayList<Integer> a2 = new ArrayList<>();
        a2.add(1);
        a2.add(2);
        a2.add(3);
        a2.add(9);
        a2.add(20);
        ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();

        symDifference(a, a2, results);
        Collections.sort(results);  // sort the results
        System.out.println(results.toString());

    }
}
```

Is my code `O(n)`? I am fairly certain it is, but I am not sure. I still don't fully understand time complexity. I know that if I transverse through a list then I get `O(n)`, but don't know if it changes when you transverse through two lists. I do believe it is `O(n)` because the lists are being transversed under one loop. Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks for your time!

Comment: It looks linear assuming you only walk down each list once.

Comment: Yes. All you said are right

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I am going through each list only one time. So, if I have a million lists and I am going through each list only one time will it still be O(n)? What will make it O(n^2)? Sorry for the extra questions I just don't fully understand time complexity.

Comment: `O(n^2)` would be taking each element in a list, and comparing it against _every_ other element in that list.  You're not doing this AFAIK.

Comment: If you think of O-notation as meaning the time is very roughly "proportional to", that might make it easier to understand.  If you have a list of size `n` and you visit each element once, the time will be proportional to `n` (i.e. proportional to the size of the list).  If you have to go through the list `n` times, which happens with some sorting algorithms, it's proportional to n^2.  If you have `m` lists and the average size of each one is expected to be `n`, the time to go through each list once is proportional to `mn`.  Does that help?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, I am comparing one element from my first list to another element of my second list.

Comment: @ajb Yes, that explanation did help. Thanks for that and thanks to everyone else for helping me.

Comment: @name But you only touch each list element once, right?  Then this should be linear.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I never visit the same element more than once? That would make it linear, correct?

Comment: @name It sure does, and this is the type of algorithm you want to have.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I got an answer to my question and I understand time complexity a bit more now. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Think you have an error: comments say add item from L1, but you do results.add(L2item) and vice-versa. In fact, some of the comments dont appear to be correct

Comment: @BenKnoble Yeah, I have a bad habit of not commenting my code until I'm actually done with my program. But I didn't want to upload my code with no comments so I commented really quick. I probably was just copying and pasting and forget to switch it. I am actually fixing my comments right now. But, thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your code is `O(m+n)` where `m` is the length of the first list and `n` is the length of the second list...

**The complexity is same as that of merging two sorted arrays**. Its just that you don't add the common numbers between the two lists in the final result..

Comment: So, O(m+n) is the same thing as O(n).

Comment: if `m==n`, then `O(m+n)` = `O(2n)` = `O(n)`. If `m<n`, then `O(m+n)` = `O(n)`. If `m>n`, then `O(m+n)` = `O(m)`. So, basically it is `O(|length of longer list|)`

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks for the help!